# How can humid air be more effective for static electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, everyday-life

When a car drives through dry air it is often charged due to friction with the air molecules. 
But when it is humid there is more water vapor in the air and this causes that the car get discharged again (or perhaps it prevents it from getting charged?). So this is the common explanation how this happens.

But what I don't understand is that actually pure water is a good insulator and only due to some other atoms dissolved in it makes water a good conductor. So the question is does humid air contain, besides more water molecules, also other atoms which can make a conductor of humid air?

Perhaps someone knows too when a car drives through dry air if it loses or gains electrons to get charged?

Answer (score 1):

Your car is dirty and there's lots of salts in the dirt. When the air is humid, that salty dirt layer absorbs some water and the car's paint job becomes a fairly good electrical conductor. This tends to dissipate static electric charges.

Answer (score 0):

The water molecules are polar with the oxygen carrying the partial positive charge and the hydrogens carrying the partial negative charge. Water sticks to the charged object oriented accordingly. This helps in discharging the object.